# Am I using the correct .yaml indentation in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, fonts

I started this flutter application. I am not able to use a custom font inside it. I have watched 100s of videos to know the correct indentation for a .yaml file and I think I am following it. But every time I run it, it throws an error saying that the fontFamily name doesn't exists or isn't declared.

Please help me with it.

Here's a link to the code snippet. Please take a look.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h5C5T8kE5LELzb8aTkG-Q42JUlps64h1

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18aVIPyIXcj9EcJUOPS5OhwIKB0wTcwuQ I added the font. It still doesn't work.

Comment: can you share .yaml file

Comment: I am new to post questions at stack overflow. How can I upload an image or a code snippet here?

Comment: for code snipped - > https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: thanks erkan, i created a link instead..

Comment: How are you using the font? I mean, when you set the fontFamily to a Text

Comment: Hi Pablo Barrera, I just added the font in the fonts directory and mentioned it's path as a value to the asset attribute. Still doesn't work.

Comment: in a TextStyle widget, as a property. fontFamily: Liu

Comment: What string are you setting to the fontFamily property exactly?

Comment: fontFamily: Liu

Comment: Have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lvR7QxIHahei1kLQozLDeWHCqsukUHgi

Comment: try this fontFamily: "Liu"

Comment: Thanks Erkan. This thing actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `fontFamily` property like this: `fontFamily: 'Liu'`

Comment: oh, let me try it.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Pablo Barrera. Really none of the tutorials pointed this thing.